# How to access the ext4 file system on Windows

Tags: windows-xp, ext4

How to access the ext4 file system on Windows XP ?

I've tried the ex2explorer but I can't copy the files.

Answer (score 3):

Ext2Read supports EXT4 and can be used to view and copy files.

Available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

Comment: Does this allow read-only, or also write access?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used this in quite a while now so no idea about the 'read only' or '  write' modes. I just used it to copy off data.

Comment: Alright. I now simply went with a live usb image of ubuntu for copying my windows files to the EXT4 drive. I'm not sure whether that was the simplest solution, but it was the one I was sure of that it would work :D

Answer (score 3):

You could run a Linux virtual machine on Windows and mount the ext4 drive on it and then put it on a network share where the host OS can read and write from it.

Comment: [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) works well for me for this purpose.

Comment: Thats a paranoid way of doing it !!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ex2explorer or ext2explore? I have used ext2explore with success. I have an XP system with a Wubi (10.10) install and have been able to "save" the files and entire directories. I just start it and then navigate to the Ubuntu directory and select the .disk file (I typically have 3 - root - home - usr -- some have just a root.disk which contains everything). I assume you really meant "save" and not "copy" as ext2explore does not have a "copy" command - as "save" is the "copy".